# Proof verification: If $H_{1}\unlhd G$ and $H_{2}\unlhd G$, then $H_{1}\cap H_{2}\unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

Could someone please verify my following proof?

> If $H_{1}\unlhd G$ and $H_{2}\unlhd G$ with $G$ being a group, then $H_{1}\cap H_{2}\unlhd G$.

**Proof:** Let $H_{1}\unlhd G$ and $H_{2}\unlhd G$. Then if $ghg^{-1}\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$ for any $g\in G$ and $h\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$, then $gHg^{-1}\subset H_{1}\cap H_{2}$, which implies that $H_{1}\cap H_{2}\unlhd G$.

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in H_{1} \cap H_{2}$. Since $h\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$, $h\in H_{1}$. Since $H_{1}$ is normal, $ghg^{-1}\in H_{1}$. Since $h\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$, $h\in H_{2}$. Since $H_{2}$ is normal, $ghg^{-1}\in H_{2}$. Since $ghg^{-1}\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$, $H_{1}\cap H_{2}\unlhd G$. $\square$

Comment: Look okay to me.

Comment: You need to mention that $H_1 \cap H_2$ is a *subgroup*, since $H_1$ and $H_2$ are. The rest is fine, well done.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you for carefully reading and taking the time to correct!